# Emberjs Ember-Data - Posting / Putting only specific models (filtering prior to Rest Calls)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with a bunch of fields, one of them is isSelected

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  ...
  isSelected: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

The isSelected field is bound to some checkboxes

```
{{input type="checkbox" id=name checked=isSelected}}
```

So far so good.  But how do I go about using store.update() or store.create() to only send those models where isSelected: true?  In other words:  How do I use ember-data to send a PUT or POST request, preferably PUT, with all the models where isSelected is true?

I understand I can use filter when returning a model, e.g.

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.filter('MyModel', function(model) {
    return model.get('isSelected');
  });
}
```

But I'm at a loss as to how to use that in a store.update (e.g. put request) call.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ember-data are you using? If you are using the beta version you update the individual model, so you can do this in a router action:

```
var model = this.get('currentModel');
if (model.get('isSelected') {
    model.save();
}
```